# Am I testing it right (unattended install)?

Tags: server, system-installation

I am trying to do an unattended install of Ubuntu Server on VirtualBox. I am using the following github script, and it straight loads the language menu, although I chose the autostart installation on boot. It pops me straight to the language menu when I choose the iso the script created.
Here is the script:
https://github.com/hvanderlaan/ubuntu-unattended

Is it normal ?
I have been trying to create an unattended install for days !
Help would be so very welcome.

Comment: I can add a comment that unattended upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 only works for first few prompts and then you have to answer questions manually.